# Python constant naming convention for strings that differ only by case

Tags: python, naming-conventions, constants

I have encountered the following code that was auto-generated by a script:

```
IDATA_X = 'x'
...
IDATA_X = 'X'
```

I am forced to live with the fact that the string values cannot be changed (they are field names).

Options I am considering:
1. Break convention and match the case of the string in the constant's name:

```
    IDATA_x = 'x'
    ...
    IDATA_X = 'X'
```

2. Look up the meaning of 'x' vs. 'X' and name the constants accordingly - e.g.

```
    IDATA_RAW_X = 'x'
    ...
    IDATA_PROJECTED_X = 'X'
```

Any other thoughts/ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: i suggest you do  not value convention over readability. `IDATA_x` seems a natural choice to me. ymmv.

Comment: What's the actual use case for this? How will you need these strings? Could you possibly just use `upper()` and `lower()`?

Comment: If the variables differs in meaning and have the same name, you lack in giving good variablenames. So i would recommend the second solution which gives a better idea of the content of your variable, so you don't have to remember when to use `IDATA_x` or `IDATA_X`